# I would like to get a whole image as my header

Tags: css, image, browser, header, adjustable

Hey,
I would like to get a whole image, in the width of the browser, as my header.
But the thing is, i get a horizontal scroll bar, and I don't want that.
What I want is that the image adjust if the browser also adjust.
Is this possible with css?
Sorry for my bad english.
This is my code

```
#header {
        Margin-left:auto;
        Margin-right:auto;
        heigth:400px;
        position: center center;    
        min-width: 100%;
        max-width: 1024;
}

     <body>
        <div id="header">
            <img src="header.png" />
        </div>
```

Comment: You are going to need to post more relevant HTML/CSS demonstrating the problem, or provide a live example..

Comment: there are a few ways you can achieve this result of a full page width image without horizontal scroll bars.  one method i frequently use is combining the css to set the images size to 'width:100%; height: auto;' on the image. if its parent container is full browser width; the image will adjust as the view-port is re-sized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could chose to set your image as background image and use background-size: cover; like this:

```
#header {
    width: 100%; height 400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: url("../header.png");
    background-size: cover;
}

<div id="header"></div>
```

You can find more explanation about background-size here:
http://www.css3.info/preview/background-size/

Answer (score 0):

Try.

```
#header {
    max-width: 100%;
    background:#ffffff url("header.png") repeat-x;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for a background cover:

```
html { 
    background: url(images/bg.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Using the cover method will scale the images to fill the container.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `#header img { max-width: 100%; }`

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, if i do a background-image, the image itself does not show up. Maybe beacause its 1400px in width, can css crop this for each diffrent width of the browser witout any horizontal scrolling bar.